# How use PayPal API Request Money?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I need to use Request Money by PayPal. I have problem with find the best Paypal API (SOAP/REST) for this. After that i need sometimes refund this transfer.

Can somebody help me to ?

I want to see if there is a way to automate the PayPal request money part.

This is a PHP web application.

Answer (score 2):

A sample payment link :

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=YOUR_PAYPAL_EMAIL&amount=10&currency_code=USD&item_name=test

Edit the value of each variable and you would be able to generate a payment link on your demand. You may also check below link for more details of PayPal Payment Standard 's variables.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Answer (score 0):

You can send PayPal Invoices to people using the Invoicing APIs.  For that you may be interested in our [PayPal class library for PayPal](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/), which makes those API calls very quick and easy.

Alternatively, you could build a more simplified money request by just generating a [PayPal Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/) payment URL using the variables [outlined here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/).  Then you could have that URL be a link from any button or trigger you want.